# How is setting potential at infinity to $0$ consistent?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

Suppose we have a point charge $Q$ acting with an attractive force $F$ on some test charge $q$ at a distance $a$. Then as $a$ reduces, the potential energy of $q$ decreases and work is down by $Q$ on $q$.

Now if the test charge $q$ is at infinity, and it comes closer to $Q$, shouldn't the potential theoretically fall? But it is already $0$ at infinity, so what exactly happens? I'm having the same problem with conceptualizing the gravitational analog.

I'm also having trouble seeing as to how the concept can be the same for both an attractive force and a repulsive force (i.e. like and unlike charges), seeing as if the test charge moves closer to $Q$, against a repulsive force, then $Q$ is doing negative work on $q$, and hence increasing its potential, but this doesn't happen, does it?

Comment: Usually potential energy is defined to be negative. So if you're in a potential well of depth $V$, and you add energy $E=|V|$, the total energy of the system is then $0$, which works nicely.

Comment: Negative numbers are smaller than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now if the test charge qq is at infinity, and it comes closer to $Q$, shouldn't the potential theoretically fall?

Potential can be positive or negative. There's no contradiction in having a potential less than zero.

This must be true since the charge causing the potential could be either positive or negative.